# Can an XIB be used to define GUI in Windows with C++?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, xib

I'm writing a project that eventually will have to run on a Mac. I'm writing it under windows and would like to make the migration to Mac as simple as possible.

Is there a Windows library that would design and run a GUI defined in an XIB file?

Comment: If you don't mind to use objective C you could use cocotron: http://www.cocotron.org http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/04/design-of-multi-platform-app-using.html

Comment: interesting, though I need to be able to compile on both Mac and Win. Preferably with as little adjustments needed as possible.